# Test View and Test Steps are showing same count in extent report 3.X

Tags: java, selenium, extent

I am working on Automation Project using Selenium. I follow a keyword driven approach where all my locators and data are retrieved from excel sheet.

I am trying to incorporate extent report 3.0.6 into my project. Post execution, it shows the count of test step and test view as same.

My scenario is Test View should be 1 and Test Steps should be 7.

Do we have any sample code or example to understand the reporting issue? Any sugesstion to implement any other report ?

Comment: @BeforeSuite
 public void setupReport()
 {
  //extent = ExtentManager.createInstance("extent.html");
  htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\Report\\AutomationResult.html");
  extent= new ExtentReports();
  extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
 }

Comment: Question is unclear.

Comment: Let me rephrase my query.Seems to be some problem in editing

Comment: Let me rephrase my query.Seems to be some problem in editing . I have query in Extent Reporting 3.0.6.  When I run my test suite in selenium, count of TEST VIEW and TEST STEPS displayed on Extent Report generated is same.                                                                           
Example:- I have login test scenario and it contains 7 test steps to be executed in two different sheets on excel file. How to incorporate count of steps populated in test step view

Comment: Please fix the formatting in your question and put all details there instead of in comments.

Answer (score 0):

This was [one of the fixes](http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/3/java/#whats-new) in 3.0.7.  You can use AnalysisStrategy.CLASS to fix this.